# Can Dojox Draw XYDiagram ?

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

As title. How do I draw XYDiagram using Dojox ?

Example: [XYDiagram](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/CustomDocument2987)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED by using OHLC provided by the toolkit packages.

<sub>(Extracted from edit to the original question)</sub>